# Extending a $C^1$ function up to the boundary

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, continuity

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be an open bounded set. let $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function.

I know that it is not always possible to extend $f$ continuously up to the boundary of $U$ since it could be unbounded.

Now, it sounds reasonable that this is possible if I have that the gradient of $f$ is bounded in $U$ since this should imply that the function can't blow up whenever I approach the boundary. Am I right? Do you know how to prove this result rigorously? If it turns out to be false, could you please explain me where does my intuition fail?

Also, if the first part turns out to be true, is there any chance to prove that some regularity still holds on the boundary? What I mean is: if I assume that the boundary is a smooth differential manifold, can I take derivatives on it?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'extend to the boundary'? Continuously? (Then yes, just by uniform continuity.) Smoothly? (Then no, even for $n=1$.)

Comment: yes, I mean continuously, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the gradient of $f$ is bounded, then $f$ is Lipschitz in the *intrinsic  metric* of $U$, which is defined as infimal length of curves connecting two given points within $U$. Without extra assumptions on the boundary, this is not enough to conclude that $f$ extends continuously. For example, if $U\subset \mathbb C$ is the unit disk minus the segment $[-1,0]$, then $f(z)=z\arg z$ has bounded gradient, but has no continuous extension to $\partial U$. (It approaches different values on two "sides" of the radial slit.)

Smoothness of $\partial U$ rules out the situations as above, and allows you to extend $f$ continuously. You can't expect smoothness, however. For example, let $U$ be the unit  disk, and $f(z)=|z-1|$. Then $f\in C^\infty(U)$, but its extension to the boundary is not differentiable at $1$.

Comment: thank you, I really like your answer! :D